# Vulnerability detected in node-forge

Tags: node.js, vue.js, package.json

I've recently started a new Vue.js project. After my most recent GitHub commit, I received the following Dependabot notice:

> Known high severity security vulnerability detected in node-forge < 0.10.0 defined in package-lock.json. package-lock.json update suggested: node-forge ~> 0.10.0.

How do I go about updating node-forge? I've run npm audit fix.

node-forge is only in my package-lock.json file and is required by "selfsigned" dependency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try

```
npm update
```

This should update all packages to the latest version, respecting the semantic versioning rules in your package.json / package-lock.json.

You can also try allowing Dependabot to generate a pull request to fix the issue. If you select the alert itself you should see a button like so:

[image: Dependabot]

This will attempt to create a pull request (this won't always succeed) and will take a few minutes usually. Once this is complete you can review and merge.

Comment: npm update appears to have solved this issue. Thanks all for you help.

Answer (score 3):

## Causation:

`node-forge@0.9.0` needs to be updated to `node-forge@^0.10.0`

### Solution (NPM)

`rm -rf node-modules`

`rm package.lock`

`npm cache clean`

`npm i`

### Solution (Yarn)

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm yarn.lock`

`yarn cache clean`

`yarn`

### Explanation

**This should cause the library that's using `node-forge` to update its own dependencies.**

Comment: The npm solution is incorrect, it shoud be `rm -rf node_modules` and if you are using windows use `rm -r node_modules` and `rm pacakge-lock.json`

Comment: Wait, all of this needs to be done? What about just running `npm install node-forge --save` ?

Answer (score 1):

In case `npm update` doesn't resolve it, I fixed it by deleting `package-lock.json` & `node_modules`, then running `npm install` to recreate both.

I expect this is a quick-and-dirty fix & may not be ideal for team development, but this is a high severity security flaw that's over 3 weeks old & needs to be addressed. Be sure to run `git diff` on `package-lock.json` & verify it didn't update anything it shouldn't have.

For me, Dependabot didn't create a PR as it usually does, as the flaw was in node-forge 0.9.0 and the patch was in 0.10.0, which selfsigned considered a breaking change. `npm audit` didn't find any vulnerability, & `npm update` made several updates, but didn't update node-forge to 0.10.0, nor selfsigned to 1.10.8 (which updates its node-forge version reference). I was using webpack-dev-server 3.11.0 which depends on selfsigned ^1.10.7. After recreating `package-lock.json`, the webpack-dev-server reference was unchanged, but selfsigned & node-forge versions were updated, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `npm i node-forge@latest`

You can try the above command if the `npm update` and removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. It updated node-forge to the latest version for me.

Answer (score -1):

Vulnerability in node-forge 0.9.0 has been fixed in selfsigned recently. Try updating selfsigned. It fixed the issue for me.
Please check the link for reference. [Selfsigned github link](https://github.com/jfromaniello/selfsigned/issues)